# Почему пишет, что переменные для вывода ошибок не определены?

Tags: jquery, ajax

Я пытаюсь сделать проверку полей на пустоту без обновления страницы. Но мне говорит, что переменные для вывода ошибок не определены, хотя они в обработчике формы определены.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  let form = $('.registration');
  form.submit(function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();


    $.ajax({
      url: form.attr('registration.php'),
      type: form.attr('POST'),
      dataType: 'html',
      data: form.serialize(),
      success: function(result) {

        $('.error').html(result);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```css
input {
  padding: 4px;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="POST" id="registration" action="registration.php">
  <input type="text" name="login" placeholder="Логин">
  <div class="error">
    <?php echo($loginErr)?>
  </div>
  <input type="text" name="password" placeholder="Пароль">
  <div class="error">
    <?php echo($passwordErr)?>
  </div>
  <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email">
  <div class="error">
    <?php echo($emailErr)?>
  </div>
  <input type="submit" value="Зарегистрироваться" id="insert">
</form>
```

`<?php

```
$loginErr = $passwordErr = $emailErr = "";

if(empty($_POST["login"])) {
    $loginErr = "Поле не может быть пустым";
    
}

if(empty($_POST["password"])) {
    $passwordErr = "Поле не может быть пустым";
}

if(empty($_POST["email"])) {
    $emailErr = "Поле не может быть пустым";
}
```

?>`

Comment: А где здесь проверка на пустоту?

Comment: кстати `$('#error')`  не равно `class="error"`

Comment: в php проверка ж

Comment: не хватает `echo $loginErr`, `echo $passwordErr`, `echo $emailErr ` в обработчике php?

Comment: не, не работает

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Во-первых, у Вас не работает скрипт аякс-запроса, потому что в нём ошибки:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  let form = $('#registration'); //у Вас $('.registration')
  form.submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
      url: form.attr('action'), //у Вас form.attr('registration.php')
      type: form.attr('method'), //у form.attr('POST')
      dataType: 'html',
      data: form.serialize(),
      success: function(result) {
        $('.error').html(result);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Во-вторых, чтобы сообщение с сервера вернулось, его нужно в файле registration.php вывести с помощью echo (как Вам уже в комментарии верно подсказал Алексей Шиманский).

И, в-третьих, `$('.error').html(result);` пропишет сообщение с сервера во все элементы с классом `.error`. Очевидно, это не то, чего Вы хотите добиться. Вам нужно принципиально менять логику ответа сервера и вывода его в разметку.